# Opengl/GLFW/glew VS environment compiles and run successfully but produces bf16 undefined error + function call is not allowed in const expression

Tags: c++, visual-studio, clang, glfw

In VS Environment and just getting started, I am only copying the "Get started" code from GLFW and rendered a window with basic primitive shape. Nothing fancy yet, but I am getting errors when I switch the compiler toolset from MSVC to LLVM/Clang. Two of the generated errors are "identical", not quite sure, with the error code `E0020` and the description of them is `identifier "__bf16" is undefined` and that is coming from a file that exists in the llvm toolset dir under the name `"emminitrin.h"` lines `47` and `48`.

The third error code is `E0059` and its description is `function call is not allowed in a constant expression` and that is coming from a file named `xmminitrin.h` that is also exists inside the llvm toolset dir from VS and more precisely `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\Llvm\lib\clang\16\include\emmintrin.h` if that helps in anyway.

When looking up the lines of code where the errors are coming from, then they are as the follow:
`Line 47` in file `emminitrin.h`:
`typedef __bf16 __v8bf __attribute__((__vector_size__(16), __aligned__(16)));`
And
`Line 48` in the same file:
`typedef __bf16 __m128bh __attribute__((__vector_size__(16), __aligned__(16)));`

And
`Line 3013` in file `xmminitrin.h`
`#if defined(__SSE2__) && !__building_module(_Builtin_intrinsics)`

and it literally says above `Line 3013`, in a comment:
`/* Ugly hack for backwards-compatibility (compatible with gcc) */`

One last note that I feel I should mention is that when I open these two files with VS, it starts to get another 15 errors and they all related to that identifiers not being defined.

Edit:

Later on, I have found that what is actually happening is not because of the compiler's but rather the VS intelliSense. While the LLVM compiler is not the actual causer here, for some reason it triggers VS's intelliSense to give such errors, but not MSVC compiler.

Now that I know the errors are only intelliSense thing and the fact that the files are getting compiled and running as it should, I have decided to either disable the intelliSense process in its entirety or just keep it as is, which I think that neither of the two would be the ideal solution here but hopefully someone has the knowledge one day and suggest a prober fix.

I will try to keep the question updated as possible.

Comment: Any chance you have found a solution to this? I am trying to upgrade an old project and hitting this same exact error as well.

Comment: @drwbns I have not. I still think if you're going to compile with clang in VS environment then you either shut the intelisense off or ignore it. You probably will always see similar errors coming up not matter what if youre going to compile with clang on Windows, unfortunately. Or you could also compile with MSVC.